# Android - Arduino Communication - USB Host

Tags: android, arduino, usb

I'm building an android - arduino communication setup with the android USB Host API. Everything is working quite well. The Arduino reads a message and changes some LED and sends back the received byte. 
The Problem is the reading of the echo from the arduino. Every second answer reads 0. The Bulk transfer call terminates sucsefull but only receives a zero. The next read returns the character that was expected in the previous reading. For Example:

Sending|Receiving
   a       a
   b       0
   a       b
   x       0

I cant put my finger on what is happening there. Maybe someone can see a mistake? Another Question is regarding the control transfers used (below) I found those on various threads for different ubs/serial converter. Can anyone tell me where to obtain details about those codes and where to find them in datasheets?

My setup:

- I'm using an Arduino Uno rev. 3 and android 5.xx
- Basic Arduino Code: LED reacts to every sent char.

  ```
   void setup() {
        Serial.begin(9600);
        pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);  
      }

      void loop() {
        if (Serial.available() > 0) {            
                 char incomingByte = Serial.read();
                 Serial.print(incomingByte);
                if( incomingByte == 'a' )
                digitalWrite( ledPin, HIGH );
                else if( incomingByte == 'b' )
                digitalWrite( ledPin, LOW );
              }
        }
  ```
- Android Code: I removed try/catch, and Debugging stuff and everything unrelated. The code is executed in a separate thread. The  "synchronized (sSendLock)" part locks the process until the UI thread gives a "notify". The handler used, just tells the UI Thread, that the value is ready. 
  The control transfer at the beginning is taken out of a blogpost and seemed to work for the UNO.

```
usb_connection.controlTransfer(0x21, 34, 0, 0, null, 0, 0);
usb_connection.controlTransfer(0x21, 32, 0, 0, new byte[] { (byte) 0x80,
0x25, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08 }, 7, 0);
usb_connection.controlTransfer(0x40, 0x03, 0x4138, 0, null, 0, 0);

for (;;) { 

    (...) synchronized (sSendLock) {
    SendLock.wait(); // Thread waits, until notified
    (...)   
    byte_buffer = new byte[1];// initialize buffer

    byte_buffer[0]=(byte) data; //get data to send
    usb_connection.bulkTransfer(endpOUT,byte_buffer,byte_buffer.length, 200); //send
    usb_connection.bulkTransfer(endpIN,byte_buffer,byte_buffer.lenght,200);//receive
    usb_connection_handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(usb_connection_handler, 0));//notify UI Thread
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks :-)

EDIT:
I changed the code so that just one bit is read. It read 5 bits before in order to test for more to receive. This did not change the behaviour. The send function looks like this:

```
  public void send_char(char b) {
      data =(byte) b;
      synchronized (sSendLock) {
          sSendLock.notify();
      }
```

I hope the shown extract of code is enough. If there are any question I'll be happy to provide more information :-)
I really dont know how to explain that behaviour.

EDIT III: Just to collect information from the comments:
The bulk transfer function returns -1, if the transfer failed, and if successful, the number of bits transferred. In the case, where I "received" a zero, the function received "zero" bits and did not overwrite the buffer. The zero i got from the buffer was still the initial zero the buffer contained before the transfer.
One of my main concerns are those control transfers. I found several "versions" for different chipsets, but I don't know where those come from. I could not find any requirements or flow charts about those control transfers in any datasheet.

Greetings

Comment: Why is the recdive buffer five bytes where the send buffer is one? We cannot see how you display the received byte(s).  Where would be that 0? Please remove the run code snippet buttons and so. We also canot see where `data` comes from.

Comment: @greenapps sry, i forgot to change that back. I wanted to check, if there was more to read and therefore interfering with the next transmission.

Comment: @greenapps Good morning. I just saw, that half of my comment was not posted. Sorry for that... The Zero would be the first bit of those 5 byte read. But independently how many bytes are read, the first bit show this behaviour, the rest remain zero. The data byte is written outside of the thread. The send function sets the global variable data and then uses sSendlock.notify() to remove the wait lock and start transmission.
 I'll try to remove those run buttons. I wasn't sure how to make those grey code blocks :-). Thanks

Comment: ` so that just one bit is read. It read 5 bits before`. No. Bytes. Not bits. A byte is eight bits.

Comment: Please use differen byte buffers for sending and receiving.

Comment: Please put a Log.d() statement in it to print the received byte. You are not showing how you display the receivbed byte. So what can we check?

Comment: @greenapps of course i ment bits, sry. The use of two buffers does not change the behaviour. I have tried some stuff without success. I'll write somethin in the original post in just a secon

Comment: `of course i ment bits` ? You look 'a bit' confused ;-).

Comment: I was writing from my phone and I'm not that used to write in english and to english in general. Apart of that the confusion part is just about right :-D.
I removed all Logs and Debugging parts for better readability. Printing the received bits within in thread gives the same result as the function in the UI thread (that takes the byte_buffer and evaluates/prints it)

Comment: Isn't there a return value of usb_connection.bulkTransfer() ? So you can use `int nread = usb_connection.bulkTransfer(....);` ?

Comment: Hey. In the complete code I use this return value to check if the transfer was successful. If there was an error, it returns -1, if everthing worked it gives the number of bits received. In the case where I received a zero, it returned 0. This means more or less, that the transfer successfully received zero bit. If I would use a non-empty buffer, the data was not even overwritten. I printed more or less every variable and checked the return value of all possible sub-function to try and find an error. Until now nothing found. I'll add somethin new to the original post....

Comment: `In the case where I received a zero, it returned 0. This means more or less, that the transfer successfully received zero bit.`. No. If it returns 0 it has not received anything. You should not have omittted this from your code as it is the cause of your problem. If it returns 0 than it did not read a byte. Probably because you were to quick. Do a delay and try again until you read a byte. It has read a byte when it returns 1.

Comment: `it gives the number of bits received. ` No. It gives the number of bytes received. All is in bytes here.

Comment: I'll try a Loop as soon as I'm back home. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@greenapps found the error. Since it is an asynchronious data transfer and the timing of the Arduino device is not known, it is necessary to repeat the bulktransfer until something is received. I used a for loop with some iterations. As soon as the return value of the bulk transfer differs from one, I break out of the loop and continue.

Thanks for the help